# Appending the parent selector to the end generates the incorrect result with Elixir/Libsass

Tags: laravel, sass, gulp-sass, laravel-elixir, libsass

I have the following SCSS:

```
.btn {
    color: #000;
    @at-root {
        a#{&} {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the following CSS:

```
.btn { color: #000; }
a.btn { display: inline-block; }
```

But when I compile it using gulp-sass, I get this instead:

```
.btn { color: #000; }
.btn a.btn { display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with Libsass, which is what gulp-sass compiles with.  If you want to get the correct results, you'll need to switch to using the Ruby compiler for Sass.